# devtools install_github fails for R 3.3.1

Tags: r, github, devtools

I have encountered a problem when installing R packages from github, using the **install_github(...)** command from the devtools package. After updating to the latest R version 3.3.1 and devtools v1.12.0, I get the following type of error (for example, for the DT package):

```
...
* installing *source* package 'DT' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'Rcpp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'DT'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library/DT'
Fehler: Command failed (1)
```

I tried a number of other (also non-rstudio) github R packages, and the problem is the like, i.e. not particular to Rcpp or DT. I am using Rtools34, compatible with the R version. I have run R as administrator and on different computers (Windows XP and 10, x64). It seems clear that Depends, Imports and Suggests packages of the package to be installed from github get installed as well, **but not in turn the dependencies of the latter ones.** What am I missing here? Thanks very much in advance!

**EDIT:** This question is NOT answered by issues with the R build-in **install.packages(...)**, which works perfectly. But rather to the devtools install_github(...) as used in point 8 of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)
(yes, I checked the other points there, too).

**EDIT:** Closed - indeed, it was a bug in devtools, absolutely not related to install.packages; solved in the latest github version. I would recommend the superusers to read the content before marking posts as duplicated, please.

Comment: The error message `there is no package called 'Rcpp'` seems to indicate the problem. Perhaps you could double-check what `"Rcpp" %in% installed.packages()[,1]` returns. If the output is `FALSE`, you could install `Rcpp` using `install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies=TRUE)` and try again.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. Sure, Rcpp is not installed. But it should be installed when installing the package DT, which Imports htmltools, which in turn Imports Rcpp. Thus, installing Rcpp "manually" will resolve one issue for the DT package, but not for other indirect Imports when installing DT via install_github or the installation of other packages from github in general ...

Comment: So, how is this a duplicated question?