# Does install_github recursively install dependencies?

Tags: r, devtools

The R package `devtools` seems the method of choice for installing R packages directly from their github repository, using the `install_github()` function.

While doing so, not only the addressed github-package is installed, but also its direct CRAN-dependencies, i.e., the Depends and Imports as defined in the Description/Namespace files of the package.

However, I am wondering if indirectly required packages such as those in turn required by the Depends and Imports packages become automatically installed along, too.

For example, when installing the `DT` package via `install_github("rstudio/DT")`, the Imports package `htmltools` is also installed (set `dependencies=TRUE`), but not the `Rcpp` package, on which the former depends (R 3.3.1, Rtools34, Win10, x64). Do such packages need to be installed in another way?

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393866/devtools-install-github-fails-for-r-3-3-1

Comment: Thanks. Thats my post and its not just unanswered but also (in my opinion) falsly marked as duplicated - thus has remained unanswered.

Comment: So are we saying that this post is a duplicate of your older post, or this is different post?

Comment: its not a duplicate. do you have an answer?

Comment: for those with a github account, another post indicates a related problem with a current bug in devtools: https://github.com/krlmlr/r-appveyor/issues/69, culminating in https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr/pull/3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bug problem solved for `devtools >1.12.0`, as available on github. Nicely, one can install such a version via `install_github("hadley/devtools")`, using `devtools`. Problem seems restricted to `R>=3.3.0` for Windows.